# How to linearize a close loop system in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

How do I get a close loop output and input in order for me to add a linearize I/O from the bode parameters in simulink ?

I seem to only get open-loop I/O when I open up the linear analysis point, but I have already connected the wires in a close loop system which is confusing me.

[image: Attach is the image]